# How can we want to connect mysql version 5.1 using java?

Tags: java

i want to connect to  mysql 5.1 using java 
then i got problem of error:com.mysql.jdbc.driver

i have use mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
by putting it in mysql inside bin directory but
running java program from command promt didn't connect

Looking your answer

Comment: We need the *full* error message. Could be, that the library is not on the classpath, could be, that the connect string is not correct, maybe mysql itself is not correct installed or simply not running? Anyway - a full error description/message would be very helpful.

Comment: import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect
{
  public static void main(String args[])
 {
    Connection con = null;
     try 
     {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///test","root","");
        System.out.println("Successfully connected ");
 
  con.close();
  }

  catch(Exception e)
  {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     } 
  }
}

i am using the wampServer

Answer (score 5):

The libraries have to be in your Java's [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) not in MySQL's bin directory.

You can try calling it with:

`java -cp /path/to/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar myPackage.MyProgram`

I suggest you group your JAR dependencies under an adjacent `lib` folder and set that as your classpath. Will keep libraries in one place and make it easier to distribute and run the software.

Comment: ... they can stay in mysql's bin directory but the point is: that is not sufficient.